# Create Stopwatch in Excel that runs while the sheet is manipulated

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to create a stopwatch in Excel in cell K1 with Start and Stop buttons that continues to run even if other cells are updated on the sheet.

I'm trying this code below in the sheet's VBA window, but I keep getting an error message saying "Cannot run the Macro 'UpdateTime'. The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled." I'm positive that macros are enabled and the file is saved as a .xlsm. How should I update the code to make it work?

```
Sub UpdateTime()

Range("K1").Value = Now - gdtStart
DoEvents

If Not gbStop Then
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1), "UpdateTime"
End If
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Range("K1") = Format(0, "00") & ":" & Format(0, "00") & ":" & Format(0, 
    "00")
    gbStop = False
    gdtStart = Now
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1), "UpdateTime"

End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

    gbStop = True

End Sub
```

#### screenshot of the modules/sheets available

[image: screenshot of the modules/sheets available]

Comment: You need to put it in a module and not the Sheet object., right click your project and select insert module.  Then add the code to the newly created module.  You will have to reassign your buttons and remove the private declaration from the command click methods.

Comment: Thank you! I created a new module and put 'updatetime' there. No error message! However, not the "stop" button (button 2) is not working to stop the code from continuing to run. Any suggestions?

Comment: you need to make `gbStop` a global variable.  In that same module at the very top add `Public gbStop As Boolean` - if you add Option Explicit to the top of every module it will make you declare your variables.  This is good practice to get into.

Comment: Ah thank you so much! That works! Have a great weekend!